# Self Signed Wildcard SSL in Firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox, certificate

I've got something weird going on with Firefox. I'm working on a web application which is hosted on multiple endpoints. I've created self signed certificates for those endpoints using Powershell, which are all signed by the same (also self signed) root CA.

In order to trust the certs I've tried a couple of things:

- Exceptions in FF
- Adding them to the cert store of Windows and setting 'security.enterprise_roots.enabled'
- Creating a custom config using CCK2 and adding the root cert in there

When I browse the site using Firefox, the main URL works. But stuff that's being loaded from dynamically generated URLs (the why of this is not relevant) does not work. I'm getting SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER error for those URLs. The only difference is that the main URL is a normal cert, the dynamically genated URL's are using a wildcard cert.

The cert chains are as follows:

- Self Signed Root Cert

  - main.domain.com (works)
  - *.apps.domain.com (does not work)

So getting a page from main.domain.com works fine, no validation issues. Getting something from 1234.apps.domain.com does not work with a SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in return which I find very weird as it's the same issuer. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `*.apps.domain.com` certificate for `1234.apps.domain.com` ?Did you include root cert in truststore?  It should work...

Comment: Yes and yes, but it doesn't :)

Comment: Is `*.apps.domain.com` part of the SAN (subjectAlternateNames) field of the cert? It might not work if it is only part oj `subject` `CN`.

Comment: Yeah I included it and the apps.domain.com (without asterisk) as well, no difference.